# Expectation of Truncated & Random Variable

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation, truncation

I have what appears to be a relatively simple question, but am struggling to understand how to go about answering it.

The general question is as follows:

What is the expected value of $S_{I}$, where:

$S_{I} = S$ if $S <3000 $

$S_{I} = 3000$ if $S >3000$

where $S$ is a compound distribution (details not necessary for my problem here)

My initial attempt is as follows:

$E[S_{I}] = E[E[S_{I}|S]] = E[S * P(S\leq3000) + 3000*P(S>3000)] = E[S]*P(S\leq 3000)+3000*P(S>3000).$

Now, from the definition of $S_{I}$, it is clear that we should have $E[S_{I}]<3000$. For this particular problem $E[S] = 4000$, and hence my proposed method for solving is wrong.

So I thought that my $E[S]$ in the line above should actually be $E[S|S\leq 3000]$

Is this assumption correct?

If so, is it true that $E[S|S\leq 3000] = E[S]*P(S\leq 3000)$ ??

Thanks for any help.

Comment: For starters, your random variable is not truncated -- it is censored above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all expectations are defined, by the [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), $$E[S]=E(S\,|\,S\leq 3000)\,P(S\leq 3000) + E(S\,|\,S > 3000)\,P(S> 3000)\,,$$
and from it
$$E[S_I]=E(S\,|\,S\leq 3000)\,P(S\leq 3000) + 3000\,P(S> 3000)\,,$$
as you stated. But it is not true in general that $E(S\,|\,S\leq 3000)=E(S)\,P(S\leq 3000)$. To see why, imagine an $S$ that takes either the value 0 or the value 4000 each with probability 1/2. Then $E(S)P(S\leq 3000)=2000\cdot1/2$ and $E(S\,|\,S\leq 3000)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what is $E[S|S\leq 3000]$?

Comment: We need to know the distribution of $S$ to find it. It's the conditional expectation of $S$ given that $S$ is at most 3000 and there is no way to know it without knowing the distribution of $S$.

Comment: If you know distribution of $S$ you can use baye's theorem to find it. It will look something like this : $E[S|S\leq 3k] = \int_{-\infty}^{3k} s\tfrac{f(s)}{P(S \leq 3k)}ds$